# Java function as method parameter

Tags: java, graph

I am working with a system represented as a graph. I frequently need to traverse the graph in a certain fashion and apply different operations on the nodes passed along the way. I would like to implement the traverse logic in a class which then will get the operation that has to be applied as an input parameter of the method it provides. Something like this:

```
class GraphTraverse{

    public static void traverseAndApplyOperation(Graph graph, Node startNode, Function operationToApply){

    // go through the graph and apply the input function (specified somewhere else) on the passed nodes

    }
}
```

Does Java provide a possibility to pass methods as input parameters and if so, what would be the proper syntax to do it?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html

Comment: In which version of Java?

Comment: Use some kind of interface, `Runnable` for example.

Comment: The "Java way" would be to define an interface for what you call and implement it in classes. You can also use the reflection API, but that's not a clean way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Java 8 and beyond

Java 8 provides nice ways of doing so with predefined interfaces in [`java.util.function`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html), depending on the type of function you want.

In your case, you're probably looking for a function that takes a `Node` and does not return anything. In Java 8, this is called a [`Consumer<Node>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html).

#### Declaration

```
public static void traverseAndApplyOperation(Graph graph, Node startNode, Consumer<Node> operationToApply) {
    // traversal logic with current node 'node'
    operationToApply.accept(node); // use it this way
}
```

#### Usage

With a lambda expression:

```
traverseAndApplyOperation(graph, startNode, node -> { /*do something here*/});
```

Or even better, if you have a static method `static void MyClass.myMethod(Node)`, you can directly reference it:

```
traverseAndApplyOperation(graph, startNode, MyClass::myMethod);
```

It also works if you have a non-static 0-arg method in the `Node` class:

```
traverseAndApplyOperation(graph, startNode, Node::myMethod);
```

## Java 7 and below

Just define your own interface with a single method, similar to Java 8's `Consumer<Node>`.

```
public interface NodeConsumer {
    void accept(Node node);
}
```

Then you can't instantiate it with a lambda but you can still use the old-fashioned way:

```
traverseAndApplyOperation(graph, startNode, new NodeConsumer() {
    @Override
    public void accept(Node node) {
        // do something here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java 8, you can use lambda expressions and method references to accomplish this:

```
class GraphTraverse{
    public static void traverseAndApplyOperation(Graph graph, Node startNode, Consumer<Node> operation)
    {
         // pseudo code
         for each element {
             operation.accept(currentNode);
         }
    }
}
```

Then, you can call it in different ways:

With lambda expressions:

```
traverseAndApplyOperation(graph, startNode, (Node node) -> { /* action */ });
traverseAndApplyOperation(graph, startNode, (node) -> { /* action */ });
traverseAndApplyOperation(graph, startNode, node -> { /* action */ });
traverseAndApplyOperation(graph, startNode, node -> /* single action */);
```

With method references:

```
public static void applyOperation(Node n)
{
    // a regular static method in the class
}

traverseAndApplyOperation(graph, startNode, ClientClass::applyOperation);

public void applyOperation(Node n)
{
    // a regular dynamic method in the class
}

traverseAndApplyOperation(graph, startNode, this::applyOperation);
```

You can do this because `java.util.function.Consumer<T>` is a functional interface. It's an interface with only one method to implement, and these are all just anonymous implementations of the interface. The other code can then get the implementation and call it, as it was provided.

If you want to learn more, you may want to search for "lambda expression", "functional interface" and maybe "method reference" in Java 8 and read some documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can go through [Function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html) and [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java8/java8_lambda_expressions.htm) is the basic usage of the same.